# can't renew math command '\exp', why?

Tags: math-operators

In the preamble of the *main.tex* file I've written `\renewcommand{\exp}[1]{ \exp \left( {#1} \right) }` so that the math function `\exp` automatically includes the round brackets. In the file I wrote simply `$ \exp{qV/kT} $`. When I compile with pdflatex I get an error that says: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] $ \exp{}`. What does that mean?

I'm on Win7, TEXLive2013, TexStudio 2.6.6.

From the **log file**:

```
 (./cap7_formule.tex
 ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
 \exp #1-> \exp \left 
                      ( {#1} \right ) 
 l.2 $ \exp{}
         $
 If you really absolutely need more capacity,
 you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

Comment: In the words of the old joke: to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion. In simple-structured cases like this, you can't usefully have the command you're trying to (re)define in the definition itself.

Comment: Try to use a different name like `\myexp`.